# "unreachable code" warning in simple single-line function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, compiler-warnings

I have 220 "unreachable code" warnings in [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/variant.html), class `boost::detail::variant::invoke_visitor`:

```
template <typename T>
result_type internal_visit(T& operand, int)
{
    return visitor_(operand);
}
```

.

```
boost_1_50_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(859): warning C4702: unreachable code
```

line `return visitor_(operand);`.

First of all, how is this possible at all to have unreachable code in this simple single-line function? Which code is unreachable?

I cannot reproduce this warning in a simple case, seems because I don't understand what exactly causes it. The warning appeared after I implemented `operator==` for classes used in `boost::variant`.

Environment: VC++ 2010, Boost 1.50

**EDIT:**

the warning happens only in Release build (optimized), and only if I compare `boost::variant`s. I use `boost::variant` with primitive and custom types. Custom types implements typical `bool operator(CT const& lh, CT const& rh)` as free functions.

Comment: I can't think of a way of helping you without seeing the real code

Comment: Can you show us the signature of the function(s) which cause this to appear?

Comment: @AndyProwl: can you imagine any possibility of unreachable code in such a function? I really tried to get a reproduction case, but failed.

Comment: Wild guess: maybe the whole function is known not to be used? Without looking at the code it is impossible to say what is tickling the compiler...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: yes, I guess this too, but in this case I would expect the compiler to point me to the line where it's called.

Comment: @AndyT: Uhm... if the function is not used, it means it is not called, and as such there is no *line where it's called*... but I don't really think this would be the case anyway...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I meant used but not reachable, something like: `return; call_function();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem myself in VS 2017.  If the compiler determines `visitor_(T&)` will always throw an exception, the "unreachable" part is the return.  If you were to unwrap that into the following:

```
auto v = visitor_(operand);
return v;
```

The compiler would call out `return v;` as unreachable.  In my case, I was using a Policy-based class and a `NullPolicy` threw exceptions.  I ended up just removing the exception.

Fun fact: if you have LTCG on, you only get the error during the linking stage, so you don't even know where to start.  Turning off LTCG but leaving on optimizations will at least let you narrow it down by making compilation of offending files fail.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else stumbles over the same thing: (I experienced this with MSVS 2017 v15.7.4)

```
class Widget
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        foo = 0; // C4702 here
    }

    void foobar()
    {
        return; // NOTE direct return here
        bar();
    }

private:
    int foo;
};
```

This was in old code where someone had "commented out" the entire function `foobar()` leaving the original code for "future reference". (yes, source control is very hard to use)

Now in release mode the compiler inlined the function `bar()` which resulted in a C4702: unreachable code warning, but it indicated the first line of function `bar()` where seemingly nothing was wrong. (actually each line of code after the `return;` triggered the warning)